# Add image to collapsible panel div angular2

Tags: angular

I have a collapsible panel using div as below

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1" style="font-size:small;" data-parent="#accordion">Employee</a>
 </div>
<div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
Some Text
</div>
```

Functionality wise it is working fine. I want to add a image down arrow and up arrow when the panels toggle. 
How can I do so in Angular2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="panel-heading" (click)="changeIcon()">
            <span class="glyphicon" [ngClass]="{'glyphicon-chevron-up': opendPanel , 'glyphicon-chevron-down': !opendPanel }" aria-hidden="true" style="float: right;"></span>
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1" style="font-size:small;" data-parent="#accordion">Employee</a>
          </div>
     <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                 Some Text
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can use bootstrap glyphicons to put the arrow to the panel header and control it using [ngClass]

add a click event to the panel header to change the icon 
and in your component class create changeIcon() function to change opendPanel value :

```
 opendPanel:boolean = false;
 changeIcon() {
   this.opendPanel = this.opendPanel ? false: true;
 }
```

Comment: I'm a little new to Angular2. Can you tell me Which is the event where I set the value of opendPanel ?

Comment: In your component .ts file which contains the component logic for example : 

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-panel',
  templateUrl: './panel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./panel.component.css']
})
export class PanelComponent implements OnInit {
  opendPanel  = true;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}

Comment: So you can control the value of this property inside your component class

Comment: Value is set for the first time when I set it in component class. But the image  change when I expand or Collapse the panels is not happening, what is that I am missing?

Comment: Add a click event to your panel header <div class="panel-heading" (click)="changeIcon()"> 

and in your component class create changeIcon function :

  opendPanel = false;
  changeIcon() {
    this.opendPanel = this.opendPanel ? false: true;
  }